# Emacs electric-pair-mode suddenly not working for curly braces

Tags: java, emacs

Up till now, I had been using `electric-pair-mode` to match my brackets and it worked well for all modes including Java.

Now suddenly, it refuses to work for Java when it comes to closing curly braces. It is still working for other modes however(checked python and c++).

I would prefer an answer that resolves the issue with the electric-pair-mode itself. Not keen on downloading other paren matching modes.